# C# XML several occurrences of a same element

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-attribute

I'm currently reading about serialization and C# attributes related to serialization (XmlRoot, XmlElement, XmlArray, ...).

I want to output something like this:

```
<root>
    <a>...</a>
    <b>...</b>
    <c>...</c>
    <c>...</c>
    <c>...</c>
</root>
```

(where the `c` element occurs several times)

But I don't get how to have multiple `c` without having them inside a specific "array/list node".

Because I really don't want that:

```
<root>
    <a>...</a>
    <b>...</b>
    <cList>
        <c>...</c>
        <c>...</c>
        <c>...</c>
    </cList>
</root>
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: It's trivial: just don't add a `<cList>` node. (And a hint: look at XElement et al as an alternative to XmlElement)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
[XmlElement("c")]
public List<c> cList { get; set; }
```